# How to render geojson locally

Tags: utilities, images, json

I have some visualizations which consists of data in the [GeoJSON](http://geojson.org/) format. I would like to render the features to a png file. There are some sites which provide this functionality. I have for example taken a look at [geojson.io](http://geojson.io). This site would do the trick apart from the following caveat: My files are rather large (>= 1 mb) which makes them annoying to paste. Also I can't position the map exactly how I would want it to be.

Is there any tool available which I can use to print a `file.json` with a suitable position and zoom (like `map=14/52.5090/13.3740`) and a background layer (I do like the one on `geojson.io`)?

Comment: The `geojson.io` site has some basic URI-based API capabilities, but it does not seem like they support bulk download of actual images.  See the help text on their site.